# Pagination using displayTag

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, pagination, displaytag

I am using Spring MVC. For pagination i have used display Tag.
Here is my Table.

```
 <form:form id="campaignDetails" action="" commandName="campaignDisPlayform"  
 method="post">
 <div class="table-responsive">
 <display:table  export="true" name="campaignDisPlayform.campaignList"   
 requestURI="/campaignDisplayTag.web" pagesize="5" class="its" >
 <display:column >
 <input type="checkbox" />
 </display:column>
 <display:column property="dno" title="Dno" sortable="true" />
 <display:column property="campaignCode" title="CampaignCode"  
 sortable="true"  />
 <display:column property="campaignName" title="CampaignName" 
 sortable="true"  />
 <display:column property="serviceNo" title="ServiceNo" sortable="true" />
 </display:table>
 </div>
 </form:form>
 </div>
```

My table row Row has checkBox. when the user Checks the CheckBox i want to delete row.Ajax call is not supported for display tag. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a decorator for any given column which allows you to output custom markup for that column:

http://www.displaytag.org/10/tagreference-displaytag-12.html

> decorator:    The fully qualified class name of a class that should be
>   used to "decorate" the underlying object being displayed. The class
>   should implement org.displaytag.decorator.ColumnDecorator. If a
>   decorator is specified for the entire table, then this decorator will
>   decorate that decorator.

The decorator would look something like the below where you specify some custom javascript event handler to be called and which will perform the ajax request:

```
public class MyDecorator implements DisplaytagColumnDecorator{

    public Object decorate(Object columnValue, PageContext pageContext, MediaTypeEnum media) {
        int id = (Integer)columnValue;

        return "<input type=\"checkBox\" onclick=\"javascript:deleteAction(id)\"/>";
    }
}
```